# Нужны ли кавычки в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

Это место я называю цитадель матери. 
Нужно ли заключать в кавычки "цитадель матери"?

Comment: Лучше только в творительном падеже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Нужно.** Судя по вашей неуверенности, такое название непривычно читателю, то есть речь идет о первичном вводе некоего понятия. Даже в художественном тексте такое лучше закавычивать.

Да и вообще смысл не очень понятен, "цитадель" и "мать" - понятия вообще говоря не очень сочетаемые. Явно что название переносное, можно вполне предположить, что речь идет о детородном органе. Такое переносное использование тоже требует кавычек.

В отношении выбора падежа вам уже сказали, но я в данном конкретном случае предпочел бы **именительный падеж**. То, что текст художественный, не отменяет желательности использования исходной формы при первом знакомстве с понятием.

Но есть одно "НО". Это текст от первого лица, то есть либо речь лирического героя, либо прямая речь. Если для характеристики говорящего требуется передать его речь точнее к оригиналу, то всем вышесказанным можно пожертвовать в угоду этой цели.

Comment: Спасибо вам, значит, надо выбрать И.п. и заключить в кавычки.

Comment: Это название магического помещения...

Comment: *надо выбрать И.п. и заключить в кавычки* - ну я не могу требовать безусловного выполнения, императивного правила тут нет. Но я бы сделал именно так. Тем более, что название такое весьма загадочно. ***Помещение*** может быть ***цитаделью*** только в каком-то очень необычном смысле... Так что кавычки точно не помешают. Но я бы на месте автора (или героя) справился в словаре, подходит ли ему это слово по значению.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты:

Это место я называю **цитаделью матери.**

Это место я называю **"цитадель матери".**

Как вариант: Это место я называю ***цитадель матери.***

Пояснение

Форма И.п. должна быть **выделена** (кавычками, курсивом, иностранным текстом), так как глагол управляет Т.п.  Кавычки позволяют использовать название в форме И.п.

**Примеры**

Кажется, это называется **тавтологией.**

Эта схема называется **trust (доверенность).**

Есть такое направление, которое называется **"глобальная этимология".**

Comment: Очень понятно и доступно разъяснили всё. Спасибо вам!